# draft mode does not respect \input command

Tags: input, external-files, elsarticle, draft

I'm using the `elsarticle` document class with the `draft` option enabled.
I thought that the draft mode would skip the files imported with the `\input{}` command as well but it is not the case.
I use the `\input{}` command for Ti*k*Z pictures and tables stored in separate files.

I've found a workaround by using the `ifdraft` package but I think the draft mode should skip `\input{}` lines as well automatically.

Is this behavior a bug or feature?

Is there an easier workaround than including the `\ifdraft` command before every `\input{}` command?

**Edit after comments:**

It would be enough for me if the `\input` command does not fail compilation when the importable file does not exist. Meaning, I want to reduce its error to a warning. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that's the intended behaviour. Ultimately, `\input` is used to read in _any_ external files to your document, so with `\input` disabled, not even packages would be included. Ti*k*Z has a `external` library, which allows the separate compilation of pictures and then you can conditionally include them

Comment: the main effect of `draft` mode is to mark overfull lines with a rule, it has no effect on `\input`,

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, thank you, I was not aware of how low-level the `\input` command is. It alters my question a little bit. Probably I will use the suggested tikz library as well.

Comment: @Mathiassa Yes, `\input` is one of the (two) TeX primitives for reading files, although LaTeX adds a few things on top of the primitive, like checking if the file exists and keeping track of a input file stack. You definitely don't want to change this one ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, thank you again. Based on this my edited question probably refers to something which is bad practice.

Comment: for your edit, replace `\input{zzz}` by `\InputIfFileExists{zzzz}{}{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `external` Ti*k*Z library instead. With that library, each `tikzpicture` is compiled in a separate LaTeX run (you need to compile with `-shell-escape`) and then a generated PDF file of that picture is included. The example document below takes 2 s in the first run, and then 0.3 s in the next runs. Also, since the `draft` option is used and the picture is an external PDF file, the picture inclusion is skipped and the usual box appears instead.

Without `draft`:

> [image]

With `draft`:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}

hello
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,1000}
    \node at (0,0) {picture that takes a long time to compile};
\end{tikzpicture}
bye

\end{document}
```

---

As for your update, LaTeX's input is roughly:

```latex
\InputIfFileExists{file}%
  {}% do nothing if the file exists
  {\ERROR{file does not exist}}
```

so you can just define a `\myinput`:

```latex
\newcommand\myinput[1]{%
  \InputIfFileExists{#1}%
    {}% do nothing if the file exists
    {\PackageWarning{Mathiassa}{File '#1' not found.}}%
  }
```

And if you are feeling bold and want `\input` to behave like that, instead of defining `\myinput`, you can redefine `\@iinput` (the LaTeX macro which takes care of doing that).